# How to enable HTTPS on TomEE 9.1 with TomEE Maven Plugin 9.1

Tags: maven, apache-tomee

I recently migrated a Maven project from Tomee 8 to Tomee 9 and therefore upgraded "tomee-maven-plugin" to latest version 9.1.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
       <tomeeVersion>9.1.0</tomeeVersion>
       <quickSession>${quickSession}</quickSession>
       <tomeeClassifier>webprofile</tomeeClassifier>
       [...]
       <tomeeHttpPort>8180</tomeeHttpPort>
       <tomeeShutdownPort>8005</tomeeShutdownPort>
       <tomeeHttpsPort>8280</tomeeHttpsPort>
       <keystore>${tomeeKeystorePath}</keystore>
       <keystorePass>${tomeeKeystorePass}</keystorePass>
       [...]
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This configuration triggers an IllegalArgumentException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SSLHostConfig element was found with the hostName [_default_] to match the defaultSSLHostConfigName for the connector [https-jsse-nio-8280]
```

When I look in the server.xml file generated by the plugin it looks like the configuration is indeed missing the SSLHostConfig:

```xml
<Connector port="8280" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" 
           sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="xxx" />
```

For comparison, the configuration below comes from my standalone Tomee 9.1.0 server and is working fine:

```xml
<Connector port="8756" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" connectionTimeout="20000"
        maxThreads="150" 
        SSLEnabled="true" 
        scheme="https"
        secure="true"
        clientAuth="want" 
        sslProtocol="TLS"
        maxHttpHeaderSize="65536">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="xxx"
                     certificateKeystorePassword="yyyy"
                     certificateKeystoreType="PKCS12"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

### Question:

I'm I missing something in Tomee Maven Plugin configuration or is this a bug in the plugin ?

### Note:

I had a (very) quick look at Tomee Maven Plugin code and from my understanding the SSLHostConfig element is not added by the plugin:

```java
value = value.replace("<Service name=\"Catalina\">", "<Service name=\"Catalina\">\n"
                 + "    <Connector port=\"" + tomeeHttpsPort + "\" protocol=\"HTTP/1.1\" SSLEnabled=\"true\"\n" +
                 "                scheme=\"https\" secure=\"true\"\n" +
                 "                clientAuth=\"false\" sslProtocol=\"TLS\" keystoreFile=\"" + keystorePath + "\" />\n");
```

[Code from Git TomEE 9.1 AbstractTomEEMojo](https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/a3e44a747270d6fb8fa6b55dd14c69d0593ee3c3/maven/tomee-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/maven/plugin/AbstractTomEEMojo.java#L1178)